# How to make an image retrieved from a database responsive?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, image

I have created a website which talks about football. In my database I have a table named `description`, which stores texts and images. I upload texts and images using CKEditor and give the 'img-responsive' style to images. When I retrieve them from the database, texts are responsive as I resize the screen, but images are not responsive. The width of the image resizes with the screen but the height is not resized at all.

How can I make images responsive for both width and height?

This is how I retrieve texts and image from database:

```
echo "$row['description']";
```

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: can you show the css that you currently have on your images?

Comment: @Sean I don't give any css to image, just when upload in CKEditor I gave style img-responsive to image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing some code to your question would help a lot. This is a CSS side problem, Taking a blind guess I think giving a `height:auto;` to the image will do.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help(:    A little css make a big change for me :):):)